# Mostrar datos de registro dentro de una modal PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, select, modal

**Controlador**

```
public function obtenerID($id){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $con = $conexion->Conectar();
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM libros WHERE ID_libro = :ID_libro");
    $stmt->bindValue(":ID_libro", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->fetch();
    //print_r($resultado);
    return $resultado;

}
```

**Ventana modal**

```
include_once '../controlador/libroControlador.php';
include_once '../info/DatosLibro.php';

$id = $lista['ID_libro'];
$mostrarID = $obj_libro->obtenerID($id);



 <form action="" method="post" id="updateLibro">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" name="ID_libro" value="<?php echo $mostrarID['ID_libro']; ?>">
          <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $mostrarID['nombre']; ?>" class="form-control" required>
          <label for="autor">Autor:</label>
          <input type="text" name="autor" id="autor" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mostrarID['autor']; ?>" required>
          <label for="fecha">Fecha Edición:</label>
          <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mostrarID['fecha']; ?>" required>
          <label for="stock">Stock:</label>
          <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mostrarID['stock']; ?>" required>
          <label for="stockMin">Stock Mínimo:</label>
          <input type="number" name="stockMIn" id="stockMIn" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mostrarID['stockMin']; ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>   
          Cerrar</button>

          <a href="../modelo/libroModelo.php?ID=<?php echo $lista['ID_libro']; ?>&accion=a" class="btn btn-success">
       <i class="fas fa-check"></i>   
          Actualizar</a>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**Botón donde paso el id por la url**

```
<a href="#modalEditar_ID=<?php echo $lista['ID_libro']; ?>&accion=a" class="btn btn-warning" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
```

El problema que tengo, es que cuando hago click en el botón de "Editar", solamente me muestra la información del último registro insertado en la base de datos.

Intenté de otras formas pero no logré resolver el problema.

Agradezco si logran resolver.

Comment: ¿De dónde sacas `$lista`?

Comment: $lista es la variable que muestra todos los registros en la tabla. $lista = $obj_libro->mostrar();

Comment: Hago un include de todos los modales

Comment: Ya, pero en niguna parte se ve qué criterio aplica al sacar este dato: `$id = $lista['ID_libro'];`, ¿puedes explicar qué criterio o lógica estás siguiendo?

Comment: Conseguí resolver el problema, era el $id